# Database not working after MAMP update

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, mamp

I was working on a laravel project, at some moment I had a problem and couldn't seem to fix it. I though it could be because of the used versions of PHP, MySQL and MAMP. So I reinstalled MAMP and made a backup of my old database files. After putting them back in the new version of MAMP nothing seems to really work. For example there is a Wordpress site that's full of Database errors like this one : [Wordpress database error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdU4e.png)

And when I try to register on my Laravel project it gives this error :

"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'todoapp1.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = test@gmail.com)"

Both of the databases are visible on the PHPMyAdmin page on localhost.

Hopefully somebody can help me with this, mostly with the wordpress site since that one was a lot of work. But both of these errors are probably because of the same problem.

All help is very much appreciated !

Comment: it's seems you haven't done migration run this command in your project : php artisan migrate

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! Sadly this does not help, gives me the same type of error saying the base table or view can not be found.

Comment: can you post your laravel error as well

Comment: Thank you both for looking in to it, I wasn't able to fix it but I found a back-up file from my wordpress site from when I was testing a back-up plugin. This recovered most of that site which was most important to me. People having this problem should check out the post Fubar suggested, maybe you can find a fix there.

Comment: Have you updated OSX to High Sierra recently? MAMP 4.5 has problems on the latest mac OSX